# Making a global function in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could someone please point me to a tutorial that can make a global "back button" function in unity?

Currently I am able to override it via "Update" function with this code

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
{
   //Do something you need
   Debug.Log("Back button is pressed");
}
```

The drawback, however, I need to attach this function in one active "Gameobject" in every scene.

Is there perhaps any method to make this function globally and therefore this "Update" function always listening in every scene?

Comment: "I need to attach this function in every "Gameobject" in every scene."  No. Why would you think that? The script containing that code should only be attached to one active GameObject and it should work

Comment: yes i mean one active "gameObject".
thank you for pointing that out... I have edit the questions

Comment: Then Bijan's answer is likely what you need

Comment: @Hikari I also added more notes about LoadScene to my answer.

Comment: i did it using Bijan's Answer.... thank you for your help too Programmer...(⌒_⌒;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach this script to a gameObject in your **initial scene**.

```
void Awake(){
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
       //Do something you need
       Debug.Log("Back button is pressed");
    }
}
```

`DontDestroyOnLoad` causes the game object to persist after leaving the scene.

In order to change the scene, you can call `SceneManager.LoadScene` with one of these options:

- `Single`  Closes all current loaded scenes and loads a scene.
- `Additive`    Adds the scene to the current loaded scenes.

As in

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

One design pattern is to have an initial scene (named e.g. persistantScene or bootstrapper) in which persistent objects such as the first script above exist. it navigates to the next scene with `Single` option, keeping persistent (DontDestroyOnLoad) objects through the next scene while discarding other objects which belong only to the previous scene.

---

Moreover, you can make it a singleton if you need easy access:

```
public static MyMonobehaviour Instance;

void Awake(){
    Instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}

void Update(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Niceee Answer!!
Thankkk youu verrry muchh for your help Bijan! (´｡• ω •｡`) ♡